# Cannot connect to server with SSMS 18

Tags: ssms

I'm having an issue all of a sudden with SSMS 18.  Today, the authentication method is grayed out and I cannot get it to connect to a server.  I've rebooted, reinstalled 18.6,  uninstalled and installed 18.5 and run it as an Administrator.  I have no idea what the issue could be and cannot seem to locate any info on through Google searches.

[image]

Comment: I'd try a 17.x version which will install side by side and might not be affected by this bug, as a temporary fix.

Comment: @LowlyDBA That what I've done.  I guess I'll run 17.9.1 until 19 comes out....

Comment: **Where any Microsoft Security Fixes applied to your computer in the last couple of days?** There currently is a NetLogon CVE about, that might or might not have already been addressed. This may or may not have introduced this issue you are encountering.

Comment: If all else fails, you might want to post your finding on the [Microsoft Azure | SQL Server Feedback Forums](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server) (Microsoft).